# SQL Server: remove multiple row null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Result  Col1    Col2    Col3
-----------------------------
Row1    null     1      null
Row1     2      null    null
Row1    null    null     3
Row1     1      null    null
Row1    null     2      null
Row1    null    null     3
```

and I would like to get the result like

```
Result  Col1    Col2    Col3
-----------------------------
Row1    2        1       3
Row1    1        2       3
```

How to get this done in the SQL Server table? I know that if I use the `MAX` of Col1, Col2, Col3 I will get only one row. But I need to get the two rows.

How can I do this?

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  How do you identify which values go together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  You can assign a sequential value using `row_number()` to each value and then aggregate.

Your data lacks ordering -- SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Assuming you have an ordering column and you have only one non-`NULL` value per row:

```
select t.result, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by case when col1 is not null then 1
                                                  when col2 is not null then 2
                                                  when col3 is not null then 3
                                order by ?  -- the ordering column
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.result, seqnum;
```

If you can have multiple non-`NULL` values per row, then the question is ill-defined.  Ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.